# Extracting row when column contains string using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file.txt, and I am trying to extract the rows when the last column ($9) contains the string `gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed`

I tried `awk '{ if [[$9 == *"gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed"*]] { print }}' file.txt > output.txt`

and also `awk -F, '$9 ~ /gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed/' file.txt > output.txt`  but they both gave me empty output files...

The ideal output would give me rows 1, 3, 4, 6 as they contain the string`"gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed"`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

file.txt:

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    29554   31109   .   +   .   ID=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;level=2;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=ncRNA_host;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  29554   31097   .   +   .   ID=ENST00000473358.1;Parent=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    29554   30039   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:1;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=1;exon_id=ENSE00001947070.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30564   30667   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:2;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=2;exon_id=ENSE00001922571.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30976   31097   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:3;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=3;exon_id=ENSE00001827679.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  30267   31109   .   +   .   ID=ENST00000469289.1;Parent=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000469289.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-201;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,basic;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002841.2
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30267   30667   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000469289.1:1;Parent=ENST00000469289.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000469289.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-201;exon_number=1;exon_id=ENSE00001841699.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,basic;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002841.2
```

Comment: try `awk '$9 ~ /gene_type=transcribed_unproc>/ {print}' file.txt`

Comment: How are you displaying `file.txt`?  I guess that whatever tool you are using is printing `>` to demonstrate the the line has been truncated.

Comment: hmm it gives me the error ```awk: can't open file $9 ~ /gene_type=transcribed_unproc>```

Comment: please update the question with the expected output; searching for `gene_type=transcribed_unproc>` against this web page shows matches for lines 3-5 and 7-12 (not the 2-11 you mention in the description)

Comment: fwiw, a cut-n-paste of @j_b's suggested code works for me (ie, it pulls lines 3-5 and 7-12); OP's first `awk` script generates a syntax error for me (due to OP using shell syntax - `if [[ ... ]]` - vs `awk` syntax - `if ( ... )`); OP's 2nd `awk` script generates nothing because the input field delimiter (a comma == `-F,`) doesn't exist in the sample data file so the whole line is the 1st field which in turn means that `$9` doesn't exist

Comment: I just updated the file so it's not truncated anymore! so sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[$9 == *"gene_type=transcribed_unproc>"*]]` -- this is (almost but not quite) bash syntax. Awk syntax is more C-like.

Next, judging by the sample data, the lines *end with* the given string.

```bash
awk '/gene_type=transcribed_unproc>$/' file.txt > output.txt
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for more into about awk.

---

OK, I see the updated question.

```
grep -F 'gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed' file.txt
awk '/gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed/' file.txt
awk 'index($0, "gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed") != 0' file.txt
```

Comment: `grep -F 'gene_type=transcribed_unproc>' file.txt` will work as well

Comment: thank you! however they still gave me empty outputs...

Comment: Is the `>` actually in the data?

Comment: so sorry about that! that was from the truncated file, I have edited the question so Im trying to look for the string ```gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed```

Comment: in the last one `!= 0` is redundant.

Comment: I generally prefer to handle numeric output as a number not as a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

> and also `awk -F, '$9 ~ /gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed/' file.txt > output.txt` but they both gave me empty output files...

Your `file.txt`

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    29554   31109   .   +   .   ID=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;level=2;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=ncRNA_host;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  29554   31097   .   +   .   ID=ENST00000473358.1;Parent=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    29554   30039   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:1;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=1;exon_id=ENSE00001947070.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30564   30667   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:2;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=2;exon_id=ENSE00001922571.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30976   31097   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:3;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=3;exon_id=ENSE00001827679.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  30267   31109   .   +   .   ID=ENST00000469289.1;Parent=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000469289.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-201;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,basic;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002841.2
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30267   30667   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000469289.1:1;Parent=ENST00000469289.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000469289.1;gene_type=lncRNA;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-201;exon_number=1;exon_id=ENSE00001841699.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,basic;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002841.2
```

is not comma (`,`) separated, it does contain some `,` as part of data, but at most 3 per line, so `$9` is always empty and thus condition never holds, your data is apparently 1-or-more-whitespaces separated, so GNU `AWK` by default would parse it in expected way - there is no need to set field separator, that is

```
awk '$9 ~ /gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    29554   31109   .   +   .   ID=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;level=2;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=ncRNA_host;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2
chr1    HAVANA  exon    29554   30039   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:1;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=1;exon_id=ENSE00001947070.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    30564   30667   .   +   .   ID=exon:ENST00000473358.1:2;Parent=ENST00000473358.1;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000473358.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-202;exon_number=2;exon_id=ENSE00001922571.1;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,dotter_confirmed,basic,Ensembl_canonical;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002840.1
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  30267   31109   .   +   .   ID=ENST00000469289.1;Parent=ENSG00000243485.5;gene_id=ENSG00000243485.5;transcript_id=ENST00000469289.1;gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed;gene_name=MIR1302-2HG;transcript_type=lncRNA;transcript_name=MIR1302-2HG-201;level=2;transcript_support_level=5;hgnc_id=HGNC:52482;tag=not_best_in_genome_evidence,basic;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000000959.2;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000002841.2
```

Be warned that this does always check against 9th column, if you want to check against last field then you should do

```
awk '$NF ~ /gene_type=transcribed_unprocessed/' file.txt
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*